# Python Convert UnixTimeStamp (with Minus) to Date

Tags: python, timestamp, unix-timestamp

How i can convert **UnixTimeStamp** like **-266086800** (*with Minus*) to **date**

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp('-266086800').strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

UPDATE

After fixing bug where timestamp was passed as a string

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-266086800)
```

another error is presented (on Windows)

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a timestamp before 1970?

Comment: The error message is clear - change that to an integer. Either start with an integer `-266086800` or if it came from a string, convert it to one `int('-266086800')`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yep

Comment: `fromtimestamp` doesn't seem to like negative numbers. Maybe something like: `datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds = -266086800)`

Comment: @tdelaney not work

Comment: Interesting.  Works for me but from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), its whatever the C `localtime` does. Some platforms may restrict it to 1970-2038. Which OS are you on? And what error did you get?

Comment: I can verify, negative time stamp does not work on Windows 10: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-266086800) : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: Had the wrong link to the docs, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp is for datetime instead of just date.

Comment: Update the question with use of an integer and the error you get. Then we can get people responding to this update.

Comment: This worked for me: get unix time 0 (jan 1, 1970) then add the time you want as a delta.  This moves the math from `localtime` to python. After `import datetime as dt`, `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)+dt.timedelta(seconds=-266086800)`. See if it works for you.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes looks worked!

`>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds = -266086800)
datetime.datetime(1961, 7, 27, 10, 30)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the parameter from a string to an integer, success is platform dependent. `fromtimestamp` uses the C `localtime` function and from [`classmethod datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):
*It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.*

Negative Unix timestamps mean time *before* Jan 1, 1970. You could get the time at timestamp 0 and then add a python `timedelta` object for the time. Now the calculation is done in python, removing that restriction.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=-266086800)
datetime.datetime(1961, 7, 27, 0, 0)
```